# Javascript: when to define functions inside constructor and when to use prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've noticed different ways to add functions to "classes" in various tutorials. The first is inside the class' constructor:

```
Class = function () {
    this.doSomething = function() {...};
}
```

The other one is:

```
Class = function () {}
Class.prototype.doSomething  = function() {...};
```

In which situations should one be used over the other?

Is my understanding that there are no `protected` properties or methods in Javascript correct? If so, what should be used instead?

Comment: About your second question (which really should be in a separate question):  Prefix them with an underscore. People will know that those are internal methods that usually shouldn't be accessed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you define a function inside the constructor as `this.myFunction=...`, it is specific to your instance. This means that it must be constructed and kept in memory for all instances, which may be heavy.  It also can't be inherited .

The only valid reason to do this are :

- the enclosing of specific values
- other types of specific functions (you might build a different function each time)

Most often, what you really need is a function defined on the prototype.

From the [MDN on objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) :

> All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object; all objects
>   inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype, although they
>   may be overridden. For example, other constructors' prototypes
>   override the constructor property and provide their own toString
>   methods. Changes to the Object prototype object are propagated to all
>   objects unless the properties and methods subject to those changes are
>   overridden further along the prototype chain.

Regarding your additional question : the following code builds a non directly accessible function :

```
Class = function () {
   var imprivate = function(){...};
   this.doSomething = function() { uses imprivate};
}
```

A downside is that you have a different function instance for each instance of `Class`. This is most often done for [modules](http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern) (from which you have only one instance). Personally, I prefer to do exactly as suggested by ThiefMaster in comment : I prefix my private functions with `_` :

```
// private method
XBasedGrapher.prototype._ensureInit = function() {
```

Comment: So private methods (I mean `var imprivate = function(){...};`) are better to use only in classes that do not have many instances?

Comment: You could say that. Personally, I see no point in defending against other coders, so I just use the `_` notation (with a `// private method` comment) and it's clear enough for my colleagues.