# Inheritance: How to emulate super.method inside overriden method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding

I'm trying to implement inheritance in the simplest way possible. I know JS inheritance is prototype-based, but as I'm more proficient in OO class-based languages, I'm somehow biased to keep the "class" logic encapsulated in the "constructor" function. Also I tried to avoid defining new members in the prototype object, as that code should be placed out of the "class" function. Here's what I tried:

```
    function Car(color, year, plate) { 
        this.color = color;
        this.year = year;
        this.plate = plate;
        this.hasFuel = true;
        this.fuel = 100;    

        this.run = function(km) {
            this.fuel = this.fuel - km*this.getFuelConsumptionRate(); 
            if(this.fuel < 0){
                this.fuel = 0;
            }
            if(this.fuel == 0){
                this.hasFuel = false;
            }
        };  

        this.getFuelConsumptionRate = function(){
            return 4.2;
        };
    }

    function EfficientCar(color, year, plate, weight){
        //Emulating a super call
        Car.call(this, color, year, plate);

        this.weight = weight;

        //Overriden method
        this.getFuelConsumptionRate = function(){
            return 2.2;
        };  
    }
    //Inheritance 
    //(I don't like this out of the method, but it is needed for the thing to work)
    EfficientCar.prototype = Car;
    EfficientCar.prototype.constructor = EfficientCar;
```

This code works as expected: the efficient car has more fuel left after calling run for the same number of km. But now I'd like to use the parent version of a function inside the overriden child version. Something like this:

```
    function EfficientCar(color, year, plate, weight){
        //Emulating a super call
        Car.call(this, color, year, plate);

        this.weight = weight;

        this.getFuelConsumptionRate = function(){
            return super.getFuelConsumptionRate() / 2;  //If only I could do this...
        };  
    }
```

Is there a way of achieving this in a class-like fashion?  I'd like to have almost everything inside the `Car` and `EfficientCar` <strike>classes</strike>, sorry, functions.

Comment: dont think it be the best pratice but `return Car.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate() / 2` should work

Comment: @VeXii Nope, browser says `Car.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate` is not a function.

Comment: This related question (not a duplicate) might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359363/javascript-when-to-define-functions-inside-constructor-and-when-to-use-prototyp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the function defined in the "superclasse", you should use prototype properly, that is defining the functions on the prototype and not on the instance :

```
Car.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate = function() {
 return 4.2; 
}
```

and the inheritance with

```
EfficientCar.prototype = new Car();
```

Then, you would be able to call the super function :

```
EfficientCar.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate = function(){
   var superfun = this.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate;
   return superfun.call(this) / 2;
};
```

[Complete demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/eB9BC/) (open the console)

It you make it a practice to call the super functions  (a bad one in my opinion), then you can build a small method embedding and shortening the getting of the method.

If you know exactly the targeted level of inheritance, it's easier of course, as you can simply replace

```
var superfun = this.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate;
```

with

```
var superfun = EfficientCar.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate;
```

Note that javascript isn't exactly the same than the other language you seem more accustomed too. Trying to apply foreign patterns leads generally to more verbose, less flexible and less maintainable programs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works. Still there's something I can't grasp: In the `Car` "class", the `run` function calls `this.getFuelConsumptionRate`, but that function is not defined in Car but in Car.prototype. Why it does not throw an error?

Comment: Because in javascript functions are "first class citizens". You can call a function with any object as context, by using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). You don't really define a function on an object : you define a function and then you assign it as the value of a property of the object.

Comment: What I meant is why inside `run` function we can use `this.getFuelConsumptionRate` instead of `this.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate`. I didn't remember that if an object does not have a member it is forwarded to the prototype.

Comment: That's how prototype work : when a property isn't found, the engine looks up the prototypes list.

Comment: @MisterSmith See [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359363/javascript-when-to-define-functions-inside-constructor-and-when-to-use-prototyp/13359406#13359406).

Comment: Thanks again. However possible, this approach is too hacky. That `constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype` combo hurts my eyes way more than having a few lines out of the main "constructor" block. I've refactored my code to stick to JS conventional prototype-based approach. You are right, I shouldn't fight the language like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use inheritance in javascript I would suggest you use this little gem from John Resig:

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Example from the blog:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;
  },
  dance: function(){
    return this.dancing;
  }
});

var Ninja = Person.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super( false );
  },
  dance: function(){
    // Call the inherited version of dance()
    return this._super();
  },
  swingSword: function(){
    return true;
  }
});

var p = new Person(true);
p.dance(); // => true

var n = new Ninja();
n.dance(); // => false
n.swingSword(); // => true

// Should all be true
p instanceof Person && p instanceof Class &&
n instanceof Ninja && n instanceof Person && n instanceof Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this, using a shim for Object.create() when it's not supported.

```
var Car = function() {
    // code
};

Car.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate = function() {
    // code
};


var EfficientCar = function() {
    Car.call(this);
};

EfficientCar.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);

EfficientCar.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate = function() {
    var result = Car.prototype.getFuelConsumptionRate.call(this)
    // code
};
```